# Validates url format in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'd like ask if there's a way to validate a string as an url or email at the same time?

for example:

```
validates_format_of :string, :with => [url_regex, email_regex]

string = 'http://domain.com' => valid
string = 'email@domain.com' => valid
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: You need your own validate method, i don't think rails validation provide OR option here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Rails API](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000087) you cannot pass two regexes in an array or something. The solution would be to create a regex that matches both URL's and email addresses or - as Naveed suggests - create a custom validation. That being said, I don't think you can validate a URL with a regex.

Comment: thanks but what i wanted was to check if the string is an url or email at the same time

Comment: In that case you would have to create a regex that matches both URL's and email addresses. You cannot pass two regexes.

Comment: thanks mischa and naveed. i guess i have to create my own validation after all. i just think that validates_format_of is so much cleaner.

Comment: @cece: And use [URI from the standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) to help you validate the URL.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks. yes that's what i did. URI::regexp([http,https])